# `multiprocessing.Process` imports variable differently in windows vs. linux

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, python-3.6

## Background

In an effort to learn more - and to have better cross-platform building in C - I am working on a makefile equivalent compiler and debugger.  Something like an IDE, but not so much.  I don't want to get too bogged down in this part of it, but enough to explain that I would like to utilize part of the open-source project called [gdbgui](https://gdbgui.com/) as the debugger.

In my ideal use, I will kick off `gdbgui` in its own `Process` so that I can kill it from the main process.  Fortunately for me, `gdbgui` is written in python, so it should be relatively simple to simply replace the `main()` with my own custom implementation.

## Implementation

I looked into the `gdbgui` source and found the relevant bits of `main()` that give me access to the functional sections within [`backend.py`](https://github.com/cs01/gdbgui/blob/master/gdbgui/backend.py):

- `app` is an instance of `Flask()`
- `setup_backend` is apparently the function that kicks off the flask server with some bits of configuration.

My intent was to do the same thing that `main()` is doing, without all of the command line parsing.  More specifically, customize the `app` and run `setup_backend()`.  I have removed some code for the sake of brevity (stopping the process, for instance), but this is the functional bit:

```
from multiprocessing import Process

from gdbgui.backend import app as _app
from gdbgui.backend import setup_backend as _setup_backend

def start_stop_gdb():
    _app.config['rr'] = False
    _app.config['gdb_path'] = 'gdb'
    _app.config['show_gdbgui_upgrades'] = False
    _app.config['initial_binary_and_args'] = ['./debug.elf']

    self.process = Process(
        target=_setup_backend,
        kwargs={
            'serve': True,
            'port': 5000,
            'open_browser': True
        }
    )
    self.process.start()
```

This actually works perfectly in linux, which is where I first tried it.  My goal is to have a very portable implementation, so I would like to have it work the same way in windows as well.

## The Problem

When I run in Windows, I get a `KeyError` which says that `app` doesn't have the `rr` key, which was specifically assigned in the above code segment.

If I run `_setup_backend()` directly without `multiprocessing.Process`, then it works fine in Windows and in Linux, but my primary thread freezes until the program is exited *and* the primary program cannot halt the debugging process.

To be clear, the following code segment works in Windows, but blocks the main thread:

```
def start_stop_gdb():
    _app.config['rr'] = False
    _app.config['gdb_path'] = 'gdb'
    _app.config['show_gdbgui_upgrades'] = False
    _app.config['initial_binary_and_args'] = ['./debug.elf']

    _setup_backend(
        serve=True, port=5000, 'open_browser'=True
    )
```

In short, it appears that, in linux, the instance of `app` is being updated as desired, but in windows a separate instance of `app` is being used.

Thoughts?

Comment: Probably due to the fact that Windows does not have `fork`, hence spawning a new `Process` will "start from scratch". Your code assumes (directly or indirectly) that some memory is share, while it is not. See [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#windows), it is a well known pitfall of Windows.

Comment: @GiacomoAlzetta Thanks for the input.  It at least gives me another path to investigate (I know very little about multiprocessing).  Any well-known workarounds?